# Database error in Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ubuntu-16.04

im having a problem, my project is working in my windowsOS, and i try it to transfer in Ubuntu16.04 Operating system, with static ip address. now when i trying to access the project it keep saying Database Connection Error!

```
<?php

$db_password = "Welcome1";
$server = "192.168.2.218";
try{
$pdo_conn = new 
PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=boldr","phpmyadmin"," 
{$db_password}");
} catch (PDOException $e){
die("Database Connection Error!");
}

$conn = mysqli_connect("192.168.2.218","phpmyadmin","{ 
$db_password}") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 mysqli_select_db($conn,'boldr') or die("cannot select DB");


 ?>
```

Comment: When you get any sort of error, it would be useful to include the text from the error to help in debugging.

Comment: @NigelRen the error is Database Connection Error!,

Comment: Does your user have permission to connect from "the outside"?

Comment: @kerbholz i grant it the all access

Comment: Is that what `$e->message` gives in your `catch()` code?

Comment: @NigelRen yes .

Comment: Obviously there's something wrong with your static IP, the firewall settings, or remote connection permissions for the MySQL server. Nothing that can be debugged from the code or a slim error message. You will have to investigate this on your end. An endless comment back and forth is unlikely to help other users.

Comment: @mario but i can access the index.php when i logging in to web it say database error

Comment: The exception message would be inherently more useful than your shallow `die()` notice. Go investigate your connection problems.

Comment: Replace `die("Database Connection Error!");` with `echo Error!: " . $e->getMessage()` So you get a **USEFUL** error message

Comment: @RiggsFolly the code is not working, the web is blank when i change it to echo Error.......

Answer (score 0):

is your database on the same server? If yes try 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Comment: even if i use 127.0.0.1 or localhost it keep saying Database Connection Error.

Comment: please insert echo $e->getTraceAsString() in your catch block and show us the output.

Comment: #0 /var/www/html/init.php(6): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=192....', 'phpmyadmin', 'Welcome1') #1 /var/www/html/login.php(2): require_once('/var/www/html/i...') #2 {main}Database Connection Error! this is the output

Comment: this is the whole message? seems like that the error message is missing. Try echo $e->getMessage().